# Dynamic colour based on vue-route-link active

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-router, vuetify.js

I'm searching for a way of customising css based on the exact or active property of the link.
That is, when someone clicks an item in the menu, the underscore changes based on if the link is an active router-link or not.
I was able to do that but by always having the same colour when a link is active. Meaning that whenever someone clicks a link, the bottom border changes to yellow. 
What I would like to have is that when someone clicks home, the color is red, and when someone clicks diagram the color is blue and so on (in case I have more links).

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
   data() {
    return {
      links: [
        { icon: 'dashboard', text: 'Home', route: '/', component: home , color:"red"},
        { icon: 'mdi-chart-pie', text: 'Radar diagrammen', component: diagram, route: '/diagram' , color:"blue"}
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
    <div>
       <v-app-bar flat app dark class='elevation-0'> 

      <v-toolbar-title class="text grey--text">
        <span class="font-weight-light">Stations</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
<v-spacer></v-spacer>
<div class="flex-grow-1"></div>        
         <v-btn v-for="link in links"
         :key="link.text"
         router :to="link.route"
         text
         exact
         small
         tile
         active-class="active text-center">{{link.text}}</v-btn>
      </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
      border-bottom: yellow solid 2px;
    }
```

Comment: I only think of additional definition styles to solve this problem,  hope others have a simpler solution.

Comment: Is this what you looking for - https://codepen.io/Ranushka/pen/KKPBYQv

Comment: @RanushkaGoonesekere it is but I get an error on this bit of code ``v-bind:style=`border-bottom-color:${active===item.color?active:''}``. It says `[vue/no-parsing-error]
Parsing error: unexpected-character-in-unquoted-attribute-value`.

Comment: Meanwhile I fixed the error above, by adding "" to the beginning and end of the parameter. However, it seems to not work inside v-btn.

Comment: much more easy but have some limitations. https://codepen.io/Ranushka/pen/xxKJNdx

Comment: @RanushkaGoonesekere Please add it as an answer so I can mark it as such. But indeed this worked.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Ranushka/pen/ZEzjdrO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is
- add a the selected class to the parent
- create css rule like

```
.red .nav--link__red {}
.blue .nav--link__blue {}
```

- on click we set the parent class in that way we find selected item.

https://codepen.io/Ranushka/pen/ZEzjdrO

I'm realy new to vue.js so there can be better solution.